# Layout: new-geometry with global and local options

Tags: geometry, layout

I have a document with pages of different '`headheight`'s. 
`\newgeometry{...}` seems to overwrite (almost) all options set in `\usepackage [...] {geometry}`.

How do I achieve that e.g. 
`margin = 3cm,    includehead,    headsep = 0mm` 
everywhere applies.

So I just have to add page by page `headheight = <value>` ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\setparsizes{0pt}{0pt}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
  \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{headheight=3\baselineskip,
margin=3cm,
includehead,   
headsep=0mm,
}
333 \chead{111 \\ aaa \\ bbb}
\newpage

\newgeometry{  headheight=2\baselineskip,
margin=3cm,
includehead,   
headsep=0mm,
}
222  \chead{222 \\ aaa }
\newpage

\newgeometry{headheight=4\baselineskip,
margin=3cm,
includehead,   
headsep=0mm,
}
444 \chead{444 \\ aaa \\ bbb \\ ccc}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\newcommand\changehh[1]{ \newgeometry{headheight=#1\baselineskip,margin=3cm,includehead,headsep=0mm,}}` and then just use, for example, `\changehh{3}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Works fine. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a case like this, the `\newcommand\changehh[1]{...}` provides a compact syntax to replace the `\newgeometry` command, by providing all the regularly requested parameters automatically, and only specifying (via the argument) how many multiples of `\baselineskip` you would like to reserve for the head height.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\setparsizes{0pt}{0pt}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
  \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcommand\changehh[1]{%
  \newgeometry{headheight=#1\baselineskip,
  margin=3cm,
  includehead,   
  headsep=0mm,
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\changehh{3}
333 \chead{111 \\ aaa \\ bbb}
\newpage

\changehh{2}
222  \chead{222 \\ aaa }
\newpage

\changehh{4}
444 \chead{444 \\ aaa \\ bbb \\ ccc}
\newpage

\end{document}
```